# Pandas df.to_records() returns a 1d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pandas, dataframe

I apologize in advance if this question seems slightly naive. I am still learning about the interplay between pandas and numpy.

I have a pandas DataFrame that I am trying to convert into an array for analysis using scikit-learn. I have tried df.values and df.to_records() to convert it, but for some reason, it changes the shape during the conversion.

This is the first few lines of DataFrame (`df`) in Pandas.

```
Index           Code1    Code2       Code3
0               99285    5921         5921
1               99284     NaN         5921
2               99284     NaN         4660
3               99285   42789        42789
4               99284   92321        92321
5               99283     NaN        92321
...
[94 rows x 3 columns]
```

However, if I call `df.values`, I get the following result, which, as far as I understand, is not an array as arrays are lists of tuples.

```
[['99285' '5921' '5921']
['99284' nan '5921']
['99284' nan '4660']
['99285' '42789' '42789']
['99284' '92321' '92321']
['99283' nan '92321']
...
```

If I call `df.to_records()`, I get the following result, which is an array, but not of the right shape as shown below.

```
[(0, '99285', '5921', '5921') (1, '99284', nan, '5921')
(2, '99284', nan, '4660') (3, '99285', '42789', '42789')
(4, '99284', '92321', '92321') (5, '99283', nan, '92321')
...
>>>df.to_records().shape
(94,)
```

Can someone help me understand what I need to do to get an array with a shape of `(94,3)`?

Important notes: The columns are all strings (and need to stay as strings), not ints, if that helps.

Comment: isn't `df.values.shape == (94, 3)` ?

Comment: [`df.values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html#pandas.DataFrame.values) does return a np array, where did you learn that an array should be a list of tuples?

Comment: type(df.values) indicates that it is a numpy.ndarray

Comment: @Alexander **bumpy** shurely shome mishtake? You mean numpy ;-)

Comment: typo, but maybe bumpy will stick...

Comment: I realized right after posting that `df.values` returns a numpy.ndarray and my issue with using that was that I was getting a different exception when I tried this. Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, `df.values` does return a `numpy.ndarray`.  However, due to the way it prints, it looks like a lists of lists.  Check by doing `type(df.values)` or by looking at its shape `df.values.shape == (93, 4)`.

However, `df.to_records()` does not return a `numpy.ndarray`, but a [`numpy.core.records.recarray`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.html).  You can see that it is a recarray by doing

```
type(df.to_records())
```

or by noticing that the dtype is odd-looking:

```
df.to_records().dtype
```

The shape of `df.to_records()` just indicates how many records there are, in your case 94.  Record arrays behave differently than normal numpy arrays.  For example, try

```
df.to_records()['Code1']
df.to_records().code1
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand why to_records wasn't working. This makes things much clearer for me.